# Magento 2: Changes not reflected in PWA Venia theme

Tags: magento2, cache, pwa, pwa-studio, npm

I have tried to updating the content on footer component but my changes is not reflected on frontend. Any idea about how to clear the cache in PWA studio after updating the content in component?
Please share the details if anyone have any idea about this cache issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am using venia theme in PWA. Changes reflecting when i run below commands.

```
yarn run build && yarn run stage:venia
```

The above commands may give the permission error, for that run the above command with sudo

Answer (score 0):

facing same issue with latest PWAStudio studio, any idea?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/208085)